# Некорректно работает первый запуск приложения Android, Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-sdk, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Разработал приложение на android с использованием Xamarin, но не могу найти ответ на мою данную проблему, при первом запуске на телефоне, эмуляторе.. не корректно работает, т.е. не подгружаются данные с бд, либо не отображаются формы... Но после закрытия приложения и повторного запуска приложение прекрасно работает, в чем может заключатся данная проблема?

Comment: повторной остановки? или просто закрыли кнопкой "домой" и тут же запустили?
Посмотрите логику подгрузки данных (возможно UI поток заблокирован ожиданием данных из базы. (чтение не асинхронное)). Наполните формы статичными данными и запустите.

Comment: Если только остановкой приложения

Comment: Интересно то что некоторые данные мне приходят из бд, но большая часть нет

Comment: Минимальный код приведите